# unique_ptr read access violation when losing scope

Tags: c++, ifstream, unique-ptr

I'm reading a char array from a binary file using std::ifstream, then reinterpreting the char array into a pointer to my struct then making this a unique_ptr.
Everything works well except when the unique_ptr goes out of scope I get a read access violation.

Am I going about this all wrong? I'm not sure why the error is occurring. I only have one unique_ptr on that data.

I've included the very basic version of the code to produce the error.

```
struct mystruct {
    int val = 0;
    double val2 = 5.6;
    std::string string = "test";

};

int main()
{

    //brackets here just to encapsulate the scope for this example
    {
        //try to open the stream for reading
        std::ifstream stream;
        stream.open("test.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

        char* buffer = new char[sizeof(mystruct)];
        stream.read(buffer, sizeof(mystruct));

        mystruct * pointer = reinterpret_cast<mystruct*>(buffer);
        std::unique_ptr<mystruct> obj = std::unique_ptr<mystruct>(pointer);

        //ha no problem reading the struct data
        std::cout << "read back: " << obj->string << endl;

        stream.close();
    }

    //obj goes out of scope and throws a read access violation
}
```

I expect the unique_ptr to just delete the object and no error should be thrown

**********EDIT********************
Thanks for the comments and answers - basically from your help I produced the code that I was trying to do so have listed it here in case it helps anyone else.
Main Points were:
* std::string is not recommended in struct if reading and writing from binary because std::string has unknown number of bytes.
* needed to create the object in memory before assigning the pointer to it - std::make_unique() was suitable for this.

```
struct mystruct {
    int val1 = 0;
    double val2 = 5.6;
    char somestring[10] = "string";

};

int main()
{

    //brackets here just to encapsulate the scope for this example
    {
        //try to open the stream for reading
        std::ifstream stream;
        stream.open("test.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

        //hold the results in a vector
        auto results = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<mystruct>>();

        //read a vectory or mystructs from the binary file
        while (!stream.eof())
        {
            //create the object - NOTE: make_unique initialises my struct
            std::unique_ptr<mystruct> obj = std::make_unique<mystruct>();

            //read from binary file into obj
            if (!stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(obj.get()), sizeof mystruct))
                break;

            //add the obj to th vector
            results.push_back(std::move(obj));
        }

        stream.close();

        for (auto& val : results)
        {
            cout << "read back: " << val->somestring << endl;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of passing to `delete` a pointer of a type different than that allocated by `new`. Actually, it exhibits undefined behavior earlier, at `obj->string`, by way of accessing an object before its lifetime has started; you just happen to get away with it (probably thanks to small-string optimization).

Comment: Is there a better way to read a binary file into a struct with a unique_ptr?

Comment: Assuming no class-specific `operator new`, use `::operator new` to do raw allocations, then use placement new.

Comment: Your struct contains a `std::string` which isn't [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), so writing and reading with `fstream::write()` and `fstream::read()` won't work.

Comment: But you definitely can't read a `std::string` from a file, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can't write a non-POD struct (e.g. one that contains a `std::string` member) to a file this way to begin with.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Deleting the string from the struct makes everything work.

Comment: @MatthewBailey `stream.read(buffer, sizeof(mystruct));` -- This should have been the clue that this could never work, due to `sizeof(mystruct)` being the same value, regardless of how many characters you have / had in your `std::string`.  It wouldn't make sense to read only (for example) 32 or 48 bytes of data from a file, each and every time.

Comment: Makes sense now about the string (should have thought of that). This post here actually helped read from the binary data properly in the first place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041755/read-binary-bytes-beginning-at-position-n-within-ifstream?rq=1

Comment: A stream is a stream of bytes. If you want to write objects to, and read objects from, a stream, you have to convert them to and from streams of bytes. You have no code to do that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 kinds of undefined behavior in your code.

First, you pretend there's an object in a place that there isn't one. You never created a `mystruct`; you just allocated some bytes of memory. Merely doing a `reinterpret_cast` isn't sufficient to create a `mystruct`. So any use of `pointer` that accesses the "object" that doesn't exist is UB.

Second, even if there was one in that buffer, `mystruct` is not trivially copyable, so you cannot just copy its bytes around. You can't read a bunch of bytes into a non-trivially copyable object. It is the presence of a non-trivially copyable non-static data member (ie: `mystruct::string`) that makes it non-trivially copyable.

And third, you try to delete this `mystruct`. But there there is no `mystruct`, you're deleting a thing that doesn't exist. Technically, that's probably covered by #1, but it's likely what's causing your code to outright crash.

If you to know why "no problem reading the struct data" happened to work, odds are good that the `std::string` implementation is using small string optimization, which stores the string inside the `std::string` itself if it is small enough. For small strings, doing a bytewise copy is probably close enough to "working" to allow you to read the string data.

But that's just getting lucky.